# Why does AES_GCM sometimes has a SHA for integrity?

Tags: tls, mac, gcm

For example the following suite:
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
From what I understand the SHA384 at the end is used to authenticate the message, which is exactly what MAC does, and the mode GCM already creates a MAC, then why is the cipher suite followed by SHA384?

Comment: Does this answer to your question? [What hash is concatenating with the data to be signed in TLS 1.3 CertificateVerify message?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88694/18298)

Comment: Yes, it did! thank you. should I delete the question?

Comment: Up to you. I've voted for duplicate. You can accept it.

Comment: Also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75970/if-all-encrypt-algorithms-in-tls1-3-ciphersuites-are-aead-why-do-they-keep-inc and more linked there including some on security more specific to TLS1.2